# Background Position Animation Performance

Tags: css, css-animations

I'd like to travel through space on my mobile device. And I'd like to use CSS to do it.

So I've created a nice spacey image and I have it zooming by in the background of my page as the user browses.

The problem? It causes things to overheat. It's a bit strange as I get 50-60fps on the devices I've tested so far. This includes an iPhone 3Gs, iPhone 4, iPhone 5, and even my retina MacBook Pro.

All of these devices eventually overheat, even causing my computer to rev up its fans to maximum after two or three minutes.

I'm looking for suggestions to improve the performance of this animation, or perhaps an alternative solution to get this same effect on mobile.

Thanks!

```
body {
    background-image: url('omg_space.jpg');
    animation: warp-speed 20s linear infinite reverse;
}

@keyframes warp-speed {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0 1000px; /* height of the background image */
    }
}
```

Here's a CodePen example for ya: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nfItk?editors=010

Comment: yes i do: [What not to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). this is not a programming issue, there is a different place to ask optimization questions. however, im not sure how iPhone/iPads work, but it is possible that they are using the graphics processor to render this animated image which causes them to heat up.

Comment: @Banana: Questions about CSS have been on-topic here pretty much forever. Given the extreme conditions the code is causing I don't think this is your run-of-the-mill optimization question - or indeed, a question about working code.

Comment: Which browsers have you tested this with on your rMBP?

Comment: @BoltClock i never said that questions about css are off topic. his code works perfectly fine, and the heating up is caused due to iPhone's shortcoming which makes it a hardware issue and not programming.

Comment: @BoltClock I've tested this on my MBP with Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, all with similar results. I've also tested it on our development Android device, which performs a bit better, but about 80% of our mobile traffic is iOS.

Comment: In that case, perhaps @Banana has a point in it being a hardware issue.

Comment: Well, if you had some loop in Javascript or PHP that hogs the CPU or memory it would also be a hardware issue, but someone could suggest why that method is causing that issue and possibly an alternative that performs better, no?

Comment: are you absolutely sure that this css block is the culprit ? is it possible that your background is being processed elsewhere as well?

Comment: I've never known a programmer in any language that would consider a question about the performance of their code solely a ***hardware issue*** :/

Comment: well, if it works everywhere else except iphones, this is most definitly a hardware issue...

Comment: maybe some information from [This](http://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/) page can help

Comment: @Banana thanks, I've read through that page a few times, and I've considered a Javascript solution. From my experience JS animation doesn't perform very well on most mobile devices. I tried this same animation with some basic requestAnimationFrame and it would stutter on scroll.

Comment: I was hoping to get a suggestion along the lines of a different property I should be animating, a different value, or a different method altogether. And perhaps a bit of an explanation why this method is so heavy. I find understanding and improving this interesting, and relevant, but perhaps it's for another site.

Comment: well you should try finding out when gpu acceleration kicks in on iphones. you could try animating an empty scaled div to see if this is a cpu or a gpu overheating issue. im not sure how background-position is being calculated, but you could try aligning several horizontally flipped divs and moving them up while changing their position back to the bottom when they move out of the viewport